# Joomla Development - Tables Folder and Fields Folder

Tags: php, joomla

I have gone through the tutorial for component development at http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!1.7_-_Part_06.

While the code is great - I feel like they leave out some explaining.  My primary question is what should each folder contain - and when should it be used?

What I am confused about is that I can remove the fields code - and my front end still works like it isn't there. So - what is it doing?

Second - the code in the table file just seems to call the constructor to the parent class.  How could this get the info I am looking for?  Is it because the JTable is being initialised when we call the getTable()?

This example seems to just show if we wanted one record from the db... what if I wanted to list them all - would I still use the same table file???

Sorry - I am just trying to wrap my head around this.  My biggest problem is I am often left scratching my head from their documentation... Thanks for any advice/explanation!

Daren

Comment: Ok - so I did some more digging...  It appears table is used more with one record from the table? Meaning - when you know the id?  Also - are you ever going to have  more than one file in your table folder?  Probably if you had more than one table in your component?

Comment: Not a solution, but something that helped me a lot in learning how to mod joomla (given their documentation in this area is not really helpfull, the Component tutorial for v.1.5 was just an "hello world" page with no db interaction) was to look at other extensions; download some (closest to what you want to do, maybe) and see how they work; in the end, you'll learn more in this way than reading a theorical, slim and static page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the documentation can be a little confusing. Looking at other extensions, as Damien Pirsy suggested, can be really helpful. In my experience though, other extensions tend to freestyle a bit and not stick with the Joomla standards (e.g. Community Builder). My suggestion is to look at the built in components, such as com_contacts and com_weblinks.

Removing the field code won't actually break the frontend. This is because (at part 6 atleast) the field is only used in the backend (administrator). There is a line just under the explanation of the field code saying:

> "You can see the result of this change in the menu manager section for the helloworld item."

You will realize that removing the field code breaks the editing of your menu item.

When getTable() is called, it will create a new instance of your Table class. Your table code can be very short because the parent class (JTable) will take care of loading/saving etc. The JTable only needs to know what your table name is and the name of your primary key (id). You pass this data by in your table constructor calling:

```php
parent::__construct('#__helloworld', 'id', $db);
```

If you'd like to load a list of items from the database, the JTable is not generally used. Instead see JModelList. See [Weblinks use of ModelList](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/components/com_weblinks/models/category.php).

And yes, multiple files in your table folder will be useful if you got more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

Fields folder actually contains code for any particular custom field that one requires at admin end. When we make forms at admin end, there could be some fields in that form that would show some desired result.

Let say - in the form, you require a field that would show all the Joomla users under a selectable list. In this case, you can make XML field of type="anyUniqueName", obviuosly this XML would be under 'forms' directory of 'models'

```
<field name="j_users" type="anyUniqueName" label="JOOMLA_USERS" />
```

Now, a file with name anyUniqueName.php will be constructed under 'fields' directory of 'models'. The class for it will be-

```
class JFormFieldAnyUniqueName extends JFormFieldList{
    protected function getInput() {
        $this->multiple=true;
        return parent::getInput();
    }
    protected function getOptions() {
        $options = array();
        $this->multiple=true;

        $db = JFactory::getDBO ();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->SELECT('id, user_name')
            ->FROM($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_users'))
            ->ORDER('id');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $values = $db->loadObjectList();
        foreach ($values as $v) {
            $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', $v->id, vmText::_($v->user_name));
        }

        // Merge any additional options in the XML definition.
        $options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);
        return $options;
    }
}
```

The table folder is created to get the access to JTable to read, create or manipulate content. A description to all of it can be checked here:

https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_the_JTable_class

and here:

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class